# Google Apps Script: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror, undefined

I'm trying to get this demo [Google Sheets Blog Demo](https://github.com/danielireson/google-sheets-blog-cms) to run. I followed all steps but got this error after running `https://script.google.com/macros/s/[spreadsheetID]/exec?key=abcdef`:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (line 19, file "Code")

Line 19 = `var headings = rows[0].map(String.toLowerCase);`
Below is the related function and here the [full code](https://github.com/danielireson/google-sheets-blog-cms).

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (!isAuthorized(e)) {
    return buildErrorResponse('not authorized');
  }

  var options = {
    page: getPageParam(e),
    category: getCategoryParam(e)
  }

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var worksheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var rows = worksheet.getDataRange().sort({column: 2, ascending: false}).getValues();

  var headings = rows[0].map(String.toLowerCase);
  var posts = rows.slice(1);

  var postsWithHeadings = addHeadings(posts, headings);
  var postsPublic = removeDrafts(postsWithHeadings);
  var postsFiltered = filter(postsPublic, options.category);

  var paginated = paginate(postsFiltered, options.page);

  return buildSuccessResponse(paginated.posts, paginated.pages);
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw the full script at the GitHub, it was found that that script had published 2 years ago. In this case, V8 had not been added. In order to avoid the error of `TypeError: undefined is not a function (line 19, file "Code")`, how about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the script is used without V8 runtime. In this case, please disable V8 runtime at the script editor. By this, `var headings = rows[0].map(String.toLowerCase);` can be used without the error.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the script is used with V8 runtime. In this case, please enable V8 runtime at the script editor. And also, please modify the script as follows.

From:

```
var headings = rows[0].map(String.toLowerCase);
```

To:

```
var headings = rows[0].map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.toLowerCase);
```

#### Reference:

- [V8 Runtime Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)

Comment: Wondering why this  throws a error: ``['A'].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call)``

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I think that in that case, it might be `['A'].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call, String.prototype.toLowerCase)`. I think that `this` is used with `call` in this case. When this situation is used, for example, as other method, I think that `['A'].map((()=>{}).call, String.prototype.toLowerCase)` can be also used. But I'm not sure whether this is the replying you expect. So if it is not, I apologize.